# Does a tuning fork's resonance frequency increase with a repulsive force on it in AFM?

Tags: forces, harmonic-oscillator, resonance, microscopy, sensor

I have a tuning fork sensor with a probe tip that would be used in atomic force microscopy. Am I correct that the quartz tuning fork's resonance frequency increases with a repulsive force on it and decreases with an attractive force on it?

I have attached a gif that I made describing the process:

[image: Force-dependent resonance frequency. No force refers to free-space.]

Here is a picture of a force v. distance plot that I found online: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gka7.jpg
[image: Distance-dependent force]
Does my gif seem correct?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.  "Tapping Mode" is a form of AFM that raster scans a vibrating tip across a surface that minimizes the potential damage to the surface that normal AFM scanning might produce.  The tip is vibrated at its resonant frequency.

A nice overview can be found [here](https://www.nanosurf.com/en/support/afm-modes-overview/dynamic-modes).

A mathematical analysis of the Tapping Mode, including shifts in resonance frequency, using simple harmonic models can be found [here](https://doi.org/10.1021/ma8024464).

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am still a bit confused on why a repulsive force increases the resonator's resonance frequency, but I have posted this in a new question.